# How can I display a hint conditionally for a text field, using VueJS and Vuetify?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to add a hint or error message or some kind of validation (anything is acceptable) to a text field, using Vuetify.js.  The hint should only appear if the user clicks on a "Search" button while the search field beside it is empty.  I'm stuck trying to find a way to do it.  My current code is below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    customSearchText: '',
    validate: null
  }),
  computed: {
    form() {
      return {
        validate: this.validate
      }
    }
  },
  watch : {
    
  },
  methods: {
    searchCustomText() {
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.v-input.v-text-field.theme--light {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-text-field hint="Fill the field to view results" append-icon="search"
    v-model="customSearchText" @click:append="searchCustomText">
  </v-text-field>
</div>
```

Link to Codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jJjZNQ

Comment: I fixed your spelling and grammar, I revised your question title to be clearer, and I moved your example code inline. This question might a _little_ too broad, but it's at least now likely answerable in some way by someone familiar with Vue.

Comment: Really Appreciate it. Thank you. I am still very green to the world of web development so please excuse any small mistakes.

Comment: Also fixed the code so it'll run locally within StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints only show when the text field is focused. So you were on the right track, you just need to focus the text field in the method `searchCustomText` which is called when the search icon is clicked. You will need to add a ref to the v-text-field so you can reference it in the method.

I also assumed you didn't want the hint when there is something in the text field, so I added an else to set the isFull to true.

Here is the codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GeVQLG

Comment: This is perfect. i wish i could upvote you multiple times. Thank you!!